# Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for packagegroup-core-boot

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to add a custom kernel module ([comedi](https://github.com/Linux-Comedi/comedi)) to my Yocto image. I've added this bitbake recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "Comedi is a collection of drivers for a variety of common data acquisition plug-in boards. The drivers are implemented as a core Linux kernel module providing common functionality and individual low-level driver modules."
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.comedi.org"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=393a5ca445f6965873eca0259a17f833"
PR = "r1"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/Linux-Comedi/comedi.git;protocol=git"
SRCREV = "af69459809c295699593604ef95b215189b3623f"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit module

# The Linux kernel needs to be built before comedi
DEPENDS = "linux-yocto-rt"

do_configure() {
  cd ${WORKDIR}/git/
  ./autogen.sh
  echo ""
  ./configure --target=${TARGET_SYS} --host=${HOST_SYS} --with-machine=${TARGET_ARCH} --with-linuxdir=${STAGING_KERNEL_BUILDDIR} --with-linuxsrcdir=${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR}
}

EXTRA_OEMAKE = "-C ${S}"

do_install() {
  install -m 0755 -d ${D}${nonarch_base_libdir}/modules/${KERNEL_VERSION}/extra
  install -m 0755 -d ${D}${nonarch_base_libdir}/modules/${KERNEL_VERSION}/extra/comedi

  install -p -m 644 ${S}/comedi/comedi.ko ${D}${nonarch_base_libdir}/modules/${KERNEL_VERSION}/extra
}

FILES_${PN} = "${nonarch_base_libdir}/modules"
FILES_${PN} += "${nonarch_base_libdir}/modules/${KERNEL_VERSION}/extra/comedi/*"
```

Comedi has a lot of kernel drivers, but I'm just trying to resolve this error for one. The kernel object is being build fine. However I get the following error during `do_rootfs` step:

```
Collected errors:
 * calculate_dependencies_for: Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for packagegroup-core-boot:
 *  kernel-module-comedi * 
 * opkg_solver_install: Cannot install package packagegroup-core-boot.
guring kernel-module-xt-hashlimit.
```

What is the way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolved this issue by adding my module to `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD` located in `layer.conf`. For some reason adding `KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD` to the recipe didn't work.